# Gosmore - No route found

Tags: dictionary, routes, ubuntu-12.04, openstreetmap, mapnik

I achieved to run an offline map server(mapnik/postgresql/osm-maps).
Now I need a routing in order to create visible routse between to points of the map.
Of course it should work offline without internet connection.

With google i've found **gosmore**. After some unsucsseful installations from source i wrote in the terminal

> apt-get install gosmore

and it was a solution for my first problem. When I did

> bzcat RUS-KOS.osm.bz2 | gosmore rebuild

After that i moved created gosmore.pak file to **/usr/share/gosmore**. 
So starting **gosmore** in terminal i can see names of the streets.
But then i run **QUERY_STRING gosmore** i always getting **No route found**=(

> ~# QUERY_STRING="flat=57.785104903827815&flon=40.94085605012125
>   &tlat=57.7874805971746&tlon=40.9422169187849&fast=0&v=motorcar" gosmore
>   Content-Type: text/plain
>
> No route found

I have not any idea how achieve it!?
I've even try to round the coordinates:

> ~# QUERY_STRING="flat=57.78510&flon=40.94085
>   &tlat=57.78748&tlon=40.94221&fast=0&v=motorcar" gosmore
>   Content-Type: text/plain
>
> No route found

but anyway it keeps saying "no route found".

Any idea?
Thank you!